# scanf() not working as expected

Tags: c

i was writing a password checking program. and i encountered a problem.
when i run the program, everything gets printed out as plain text instead of allowing user input.I have also tried to run other programs that worked before but they are all having the same problem. Here is my code and an image of the problem [image: the imege]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()

{
int password, pass2;
char name;
printf("\nInput your name: ");
scanf("%c", &name);

printf("\nEnter your password(must be a number): ");
scanf("%d, &password");

printf("\nRe-enter your password(must be a number): ");
scanf("%d, &pass2");

 if("password == pass2")
{
    printf("welcome %c", name);
}
else{
    printf("sorry your passwords did not match!");
}
getch();
```

}

Comment: This does not look like it needs an image. Just copy the output of the program as plain text into your post (format it as `code`). Although that line `if("password == pass2")` looks yucky enough to advise you to take another look at a C programming book.

Comment: You know that `char` means a single character, right?  How do you plan to store a name in there?

Comment: @M.M i found that out, so what can i use to store a name?

Comment: Take the habit of compiling with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and using the debugger (`gdb`) to run your program step by step (or with breakpoints, etc...) and understand what is the computer doing. Also, take several days to read some good books about C programming (and even programming in general, e.g.  [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)...); you look *very confused*; at last, avoid putting an image if you can copy & paste code (& output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made some mistakes,

```
scanf("%d, &password");
```

The correct way of calling a **scanf** is the following.

```
 scanf ( const char * format, ... );
```

The correct way of coding in C this line would be.

```
scanf("%d", &password);
```

Also have an error in line 15.

```
if("password == pass2")
```

The correct way of comparing numbers would be

```
if(password == pass2)
```

**The char problem.**

You are declaring a char, that in C is a **single character**.

When reading a **string**, you should declare a array of char, and to read/write it you should use **%s**.

There are problems with this approach too, words like *"firstname lastname"* will not work, but I will put this as something to you work with.

---

It's normal some mistakes when learning, you can check some help in the

http://www.cplusplus.com/

For a more "guided" approach you can also check this

http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/

---

Here is the "correct" final code. (it's still need some improves but will run as expected.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int password, pass2;
    char name[20];
    printf("\nInput your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("\nEnter your password(must be a number): ");
    scanf("%d", &password);

    printf("\nRe-enter your password(must be a number): ");
    scanf("%d", &pass2);

    if(password == pass2)
    {
        printf("welcome %s", name);
    }
    else{
        printf("sorry your passwords did not match!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am still getting the same problem

Comment: When he types `node` as in the image, then the `n` is read into the variable `name` — leaving the `ode` to be interpreted as a number by the next `scanf()`.  This is going to fail — twice, in rapid succession, without the user entering anything more.  There's no guarantee about whether the two uninitialized variables `password` and `pass2` contain the same value or not.  The code needs `char name[50];` and `if (scanf("%49s", name) != 1) { … process error… }` (note there's no `&` here!) and `if (scanf("%d", &password) != 1) { …process error… }` and similarly for `pass2`.

Comment: I Tested it poorly, i rewrote the answer and now should work fine.

Comment: Using `scanf("%s", name);` is as safe as `gets(name)`.  Suggest using `fgets()`